# How to switch focus to the app based on its PID from CLI?

Tags: command-line, window-manager

I've started using Firefox with multiple profiles, however sometimes I'm lost and I can't find the right window.

For example given I've the process with PID 1234 such as:

```
$ ps wuax | grep -w Foo
kenorb           1234  /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox -P Foo
```

how can I switch the current focus to it based on its PID?

Comment: Well, you could `kill -STOP 1234`, look which Firefox stops responding, and then use `kill -CONT 1234` to proceed. But I hope somebody has a better idea :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an *example* **AppleScript** *code* snippet that will bring the windows of the `unix id` (PID) for process showing `Foo` in its *command* to the front:

```
set thisUnixID to (do shell script "ps wx | awk '/[F]oo/{print $1}'") as integer

tell application "System Events"
    set frontmost of every process whose unix id is thisUnixID to true
end tell
```

Note that this example code can be reworked to ask for a profile name and go from there and can be done either as an AppleScript application or a bash script depending on your requirements.

Also note that the *square braces* around the first character of "Foo" are there so it only returns the **PID** for the appropriate target, not e.g. the **PID** of `awk` looking for "Foo" without the square braces.

---

Here is the slighty modified version which finds the Firefox window with specific profile name:

```
#!/usr/bin/env osascript
set PID to (do shell script "pgrep -f -- 'firefox -P Foo'") as integer

tell application "System Events"
  set frontmost of every process whose unix id is PID to true
end tell
```

Comment: Just a heads up for those that are unaware: 1. If your awk results return more than a single PID, the above script will fail. 2. If your awk command can be found by itself, it may return the wrong PID. So I used the following shell one-liner: `ps wx | awk '/awk/{next} /Brave/{print $1}' | head -n1`